# Can't created button_to for deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have resources:

`resources :articles`

For some reason I can't find the path of the method delete for it. I need to do that for `button_to`.

```
#from pry

 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.articles_path("432432", {method: :delete}) # => "/articles/432432?method=delete"

 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.articles_path(id: "432432", method: :delete)
=> "/articles/432432?method=delete"

 Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.articles_path({ controller: :articles, action: :delete, id: "432432"})
=> "/articles?action=delete&id=432432"

# and so on...
```

The same thing for the button:

```
 <%= button_to 'Destroy', { controller: :articles, action: :delete, id: 'some_id' }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

It says

`No route matches {:controller=>\"articles\", :action=>\"delete\", :id=>\"43433\"}`

Why? I figure I'm not using the right arguments or mixing up their order.

Note I'm using my custom id I obtain from somewhere, so I can't do this:

```
articles_path(@article)...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails4 it is definitely the `destroy` method instead of `delete` when using `resources` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

That was the case in rails3 too: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

So this should work:

```
 <%= button_to 'Destroy', { controller: :articles, action: :destroy, id: 'some_id' }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: even though the real name of the method is delete?

Comment: the controller action is called `destroy`. `delete` refers to the HTTP-method delete.

Comment: If you have a delete function implemented in the controller and want to use that, you have to define a route for it. `resources :articles` only defines the routes stated in the guide. Using `action: :destroy` in the button_to will call the inherited `destroy` function, not your `delete` function.